# running xsl transform mutltiple time results in xml:lang attribute replaced with lang attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, dita

I am running an XSL transform to change some DITA XML. The first part of the code finds a matching number format - e.g. 574-1234 - and places the number in a keyref. This works as expected.

However, I want to add an `xml:lang` attribute to matching instances too. This all works the first time I run the transform. But if I run the transform a second time, the `xml:lang` attribute changes to `lang` only.

Why!?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xml:lang="en-US"
  xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs ditaarch xsl" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="."
      regex="(574-\d\d\d\d)">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="matches(., '574-\d\d\d\d')">
            <ph>
              <xsl:attribute name="keyref">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="xml:lang">
                <xsl:text>en-us</xsl:text>
              </xsl:attribute>
            </ph>
          </xsl:when>
          <!-- End product family xsl -->
        </xsl:choose>

      </xsl:matching-substring>

      <!-- Let everything non matching fall thruough -->
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>

    </xsl:analyze-string>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd">
<concept id="concept_elb_jny_l4b">
    <title xml:lang="en-us">test</title>
    <conbody>
        <p>574-1234</p>
    </conbody>
</concept>
```

First time output, xml:lang added correctly to the keyref. xml:lang changes to lang in the title element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd">
<concept id="concept_elb_jny_l4b">
   <title lang="en-us">test</title>
   <conbody>
      <p>
         <ph keyref="574-1234" xml:lang="en-us"/>
      </p>
   </conbody>
</concept>
```

Second time running the transform, only lang attributes remain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd">
<concept id="concept_elb_jny_l4b">
   <title lang="en-us">test</title>
   <conbody>
      <p>
         <ph keyref="574-1234" lang="en-us"/>
      </p>
   </conbody>
</concept>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which XSLT engine? What do you mean by "second time"?  A completely separate execution? Second time on the same input file? What about the third time? Fourth time?   Please clarify.

Comment: Hi Jim, yes a complete second execution on the same input file. On the second execution, the xml:lang attribute from the first execution changes to lang. I'm using OxygenXML to run this transform on the content, and it's using transform Saxon-PE 9.8.0.12. Thanks

Comment: It would also help if you posted a minimal but complete XSLT sample to allow others to easily reproduce the problem. Have you tried to run that with Saxon outside of oXygen?

Comment: Hi - I think my code is now a bit more complete, if that's what you mean Martin. No I have not yet tried this outside of Oxygen.

Comment: Update: the transform also removes existing instances of xml:lang attributes, outside of matching strings, and removes the "xml:" suffix as well. I think the issue is related to xml namespaces but I don't quite understand how that works.

Comment: I agree with @MartinHonnen, please post a small XML snippet and a complete XSLT stylesheet to showcase the problem. The XSLT you posted only seems to output text content.

Comment: What happens if you run it, then completely close OxygenXML, relaunch OxygenXML, and run it again?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like transformation copies `local-name` of your attributes.

Please check if you use template similar to this:

```
<xsl:template match="@*" priority="-1">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

If yes, then use `xsl:copy` instead of `xsl:attribute`.
Following template should fix it:

```
<xsl:template match="@*" priority="-1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yes this fixed my issue. I did have that code that you mention. In the end I also used   ```copy-namespaces="no"``` attribute on the copy element as I was getting some other crud, even though I had defined namespaces at the beginning of the stylesheet. Thanks for you help.